# Manual instantiation of ActiveRecord connection pool results in jumbled reads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mariadb, mysql2

I’m not so new to Rails but when I come across instances like this it sure feels like it. Perhaps some wiser eyes might shed some light on this puzzling situation.

For a project we created a database connection manually via ActiveRecord due to the manner in which we retrieve the connection details. I’ll start off by explaining the result of the effect:

```
Reading from the database (MariaDB using the MySQL2 gem) using raw sql results in jumbled data at times, others only column names inserted in the field values and at other the correct type of data but clearly associated with a different request
```

Below is the code used to create the Connection, done as a ||= singleton and the connection details read into :database1. I’m interested in understanding the problem more than the solution, but a solution would be quite nice too.

```
class DataSources
    def self.database1
        @database1 ||= ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:database1).connection
        @database1.reconnect! unless @database1.active?
        @database1
    end
end
```

From what I understood going through the docs this should create a connection pool and automatically handle the threading and pooling.

When using the connection I simply called the connection pool:

`query_result = DataSources.exec_query("<some raw sql>")`

or

`query_result = DataSources.query("<some raw sql>")`

I should point Out that this is only for reads (`select...`).
My immediate thought was that this is the same connection being read by different calls, a form of a race condition, as it only happened when multiple requests happened in the same short span of time close enough together.

A fellow developer thinks the issue might be “due to the ||=” but I don’t understand how that could be the case, and we don’t want to create a new connection pool each time a query needs to be processed and set up n number of connections to the database.

I expect not to see another queries results when executing a specific query or column names in the place of field data. Something tells me this is a lock not happening somewhere or the same connection from the connection pool being used every time.

Comment: Thanks. Why does changing to a class variable influence the reads being polluted? Wouldn't using a class variable result in the same as using this singleton? I'm a bit unclear on that.

Comment: I don't understand. Wouldn't instance variables be less likely to cause issues, if instead of a single connection pool multiple get spun up at each call?

Comment: You are NOT creating a connection pool but a single connection. This single connection must not be shared between threads. With your code though, it will be used by concurrent threads which will cause random undefined behavior as you have seen. You want to use a connection pool instead and checkout connections from there.